# Shortcut command for highlighting text in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?

Tags: acrobat, adobe-reader

Is there a shortcut command for highlighting text (as opposed to right-click, highlight) in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general software support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than selecting with the text selection tool then highlighting. Just turn on the highlight tool and select.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, however, I am looking for a shortcut command. Thanks though!

Comment: There isn't a shortcut for the highlight exactly. However, to enable single-key shortcuts, open the Preferences dialog box (Edit > Preferences), and under General, select the Use Single-Key Accelerators To Access Tools option. Then use Shift-U to cycle through highlighting tools in the order Highlighter,Underline Text, Cross Out Text.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!